# why flutter html keep rendering all the time with no stop when show gif image

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

Today I found my flutter(2.0.x) app suddenly keep rending with no stopping although the screen not touch or any other opertate. This is what looks like:

[image]

I found if the flutter html rendered page had gif image, even exit the page, the UI will keep rending all the time. I have made a minimal examle, this is the main page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

import 'app.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      checkerboardOffscreenLayers: true,
      checkerboardRasterCacheImages: true,
      showPerformanceOverlay: true,
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              Widget page = LearnApp();
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page),
              );
            }, child: Text("Click")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

and this is a new page render a gif by flutter html:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

class LearnApp extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("widget.title"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(

        child: Html(
            data: "<p><img src=\"https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/mw690/006v119zly1gsu8ni6jbbg30a007q1l2.gif\" /></p>"
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

When I exit the `LearnApp` page, the UI thread still running with no stop in background. I am turn on the debugging like this:

```
checkerboardOffscreenLayers: true,
checkerboardRasterCacheImages: true,
showPerformanceOverlay: true,
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: A `setState` loop probably, Please share the code.

Comment: the code is too much, I do not know which code should I paste, I set some breakpoint in code but no one triggered. @omidh

Comment: this is the project code: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open

Comment: Which page is giving you trouble?

Comment: the articlelist page and the articledetail page, I found both the page will trigger the rerender infinility. @omidh